# Error loading sample django-bootstrap3 template

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm still new to Django and Bootstrap so I'm trying out the django-bootstrap package: https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3

The sample template that is included on that page (with a change of url in form action):

```
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{# Load CSS and JavaScript #}

{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript %}

{# Display a form #}

<form action="/search/" method="post" class="form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% bootstrap_form form %}
        {% bootstrap_form_buttons %}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                        {% bootstrap_icon "star" %} Submit
                </button>
        {% end_bootstrap_form_buttons %}
</form>
```

Gives me the error:

```
BootstrapError at /
Parameter "form" should contain a valid Django Form.
```

on this line

```
{% bootstrap_form form %}
```

I'm not exactly sure what's the problem is since this is the sample template that's included in that README.

Comment: try {% bootstrap_form|form %}

Comment: I have happened to stumble into the same error. 

My mistake was that I was not inheriting 'FormView' in the class that pointed to the template that contains the form.

Answer (score 4):

`{% bootstrap_form form %}` is a template tag provided by django-bootstrap3 that expect a django form instance, so the "`form`" parameter is the context variable mentioned in  [displaying-a-form-using-a-template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/#displaying-a-form-using-a-template) from django docs.

Create the form as explained in that page, and then replace the html code they use in template:

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

by the sample code in your question.

Now `Parameter "form" contains a valid Django Form`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

You just need to provide an object form server side, which must have a context name "form".

In your views.py, include something like this

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    from django import forms
    class NameForm(forms.Form):
        your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)

    template = "your_template.html"
    context = { "form" : NameForm() }
    return render( request, template, context )
```

Now you should not have any error.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

try this

```html
{# Load the tag library #}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{# Load CSS and JavaScript #}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript %}

{# Display django.contrib.messages as Bootstrap alerts #}
{% bootstrap_messages %}

{# Display a form #}
<form action="/url/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the bootstrap_button tags. I tried to find them as well, but they are not declared in the source...

Comment: Eh I asked this awhile ago, currently I'm just using bootstrap by itself without the django package since it gives me greater control.

Answer (score 0):

Put `{% extends 'bootstrap3/bootstrap3.html' %}` at the beginning of your snippet. It's supposed to be your file, bootstrap3.html is at this placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

Error is pretty straightforward, make sure you pass valid django form. I was passing `form.as_p()` instead of `form` in my view and got this error. Took me a while to notice. May be it will still help somebody.

Answer (score -1):

for django 1.8 use `{{ form }}` instead of `{{ form.as_p }}` as in django 1.6, for this minor change can cause an error

please see django 1.8 official documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#the-template

```
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{# Display a form #}

<form action="/submit/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```